# Get selected button's value from Polymer radio group with jquery

Tags: jquery, polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to get the value from a polymer 1.0 radio group and save it to a database:

**HTML:**

```
<paper-radio-group selected="small">
  <paper-radio-button name="small">Small</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="medium">Medium</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="large">Large</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

**Script:**

```
var size = $('input[selected]:checked').val();
```

Is there a simple way with jQuery? Do I need to add an id on paper-radio-group?

Comment: You should not need or use jquery with Polymer. Keep the codebase  lite and native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need a id you can use Polymers databinding

```
<paper-radio-group selected="{{radioSelected}}">
  <paper-radio-button name="small">Small</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="medium">Medium</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="large">Large</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

Then in a custom element the value would be `this.radioSelected` or if you are using a autobinding template "dom-bind" the value would be `app.radioSelected` if app referred to the dom-bind tempate

without using databinding you would need a id.

```
<paper-radio-group id="radio">
  <paper-radio-button name="small">Small</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="medium">Medium</paper-radio-button>
  <paper-radio-button name="large">Large</paper-radio-button>
</paper-radio-group>
```

I don't Jquery so I am using plain JS here

```
document.querySelector('#radio').selected
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am using databindings. I need jquery as im saving the result as json. Im not great with jquery myself so this part is confusing without an id.